# cannot copy datetime values from one column to other with correct formattign in pandas based on value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a part of a DataFrame in the following format:

markdown

| emp_code | emp_name | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-07 | H |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-14 | H |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-21 | H |
| 42 | B | 2023-04-07 | H |

with the following data types:

markdown

| column | dtype |
| --- | --- |
| emp_code | int64 |
| emp_name | object |
| status | object |
| date | datetime64[ns] |

I have added new columns holiday_count and holiday_date to it using the following function:

```
def custom_agg(group):
    holiday_count = (group['status'] == 'H').sum()
    holiday_date = np.where(group['status'] == "H", str(group["date"]), str())
    return pd.Series({
        'holiday_count': holiday_count,
        'holiday_date': holiday_date
    })
```

and I am calling this custom_agg function as :
`result_df = df.groupby(['emp_code','emp_name']).apply(custom_agg).reset_index()`

This gives me a DataFrame in the following format:

| emp_code | emp_name | holiday_count | holiday_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | A | 3 | ['0 2023-04-07\n1 2023-04-14\n2 2023-04-21\nName: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]' '0 2023-04-07\n1 2023-04-14\n2 2023-04-21\nName: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]' '0 2023-04-07\n1 2023-04-14\n2 2023-04-21\nName: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]'] |
| 42 | B | 3 | [0 2023-04-07\n1 2023-04-14\n2 2023-04-2... |
| 43 | C | 3 | [0 2023-04-07\n1 2023-04-14\n2 2023-04-2... |
| 44 | D | 3 | [0 2023-04-07\n1 2023-04-14\n2 2023-04-2... |

However, in the result, the dates are getting repeated as an array based on the value of holiday_count, and it's also printing metadata inside the holiday_date column.

I am unable to parse the datetime object as it is, which is why I am trying to convert it to a string, but this gives me the formatting issue.

So far, I have tried to use:

`holiday_date = np.where(group['status'] == "H", (group["date"].values), str())` 
But this results in an error:
"no common Dtype exists for given inputs."

How can I reliably copy the date from one column to the other without causing a formatting issue?

In essence what I am trying to achieve is to calculate how many holidays an employee has taken based on status value, if status is equal to "H", it should increase the holiday_count by 1 and add the said date for row inside the holiday date column.
If status is not equal to "H", it should check what the status is and i.e *AL,*SL where * is the no of leaves and add that specific date to availed_leave_date column while increasing the count of availed_leaves counter by * (same goes for SL and increasing the sick_leave_count by 1). and show the data at end as a dataframe printed to excel.

this is part of data frame with varying status values:

| emp_code | emp_name | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-07 | H |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-14 | H |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-21 | H |
| 42 | B | 2023-04-07 | H |
| 05 | J | 2023-04-03 | 1SL |
| 31 | P | 2023-04-10 | 1AL |

upon performing aggregation on this date frame, it should return sum of types of leaves i.e. total_holiday_leaves, total_availed_leaves and total_sick_leaves along with their date in the following format.

| emp_code | emp_name | holiday_date | total_holiday_leaves | sick_date | total_sick_leaves | availed_date | total_availed_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | A | 2023-04-07,2023-04-1420,23-04-21 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 05 | J |  |  | 2023-04-03 | 1 |  |  |
| 31 | P |  |  |  |  | 2023-04-10 | 1 |

Comment: Your *I/O* don't match (*see e.g* `emp_code` *that is* `43`). Also, how do you call `custom_agg` ?

Comment: edited the question to be more clarifying.

Comment: Your *I/O* still don't match and your code throws a `NameError: name 'availed_leave_count' is not defined`.

Comment: my apologies, it was part of other solution which I am trying to implement at my end.

Comment: No worries! Can you make a meaningful example (*e.g where status isn't* `H`) and show the exact expected output  (**that matches the given input**) ?

Comment: I have edited the question to cover my whole problem statement and with expected output and variance in sample input data.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve your desired results is to build a dict of holiday types and the desired column names for the count and then iterate that dictionary to aggregate the dates for that holiday type (as a comma separated string and a count):

```
status = {
    'H' : ['holiday_date', 'total_holiday_leaves'],
    '1SL' : ['sick_date', 'total_sick_leaves'],
    '1AL' : ['availed_date', 'total_availed_date']
}

out = pd.DataFrame()
for st, names in status.items():
    tmp = df[df['status'] == st].groupby(['emp_code', 'emp_name']).agg({ 'date' : ','.join, 'status' : 'count' }).set_axis(names, axis=1)
    out = pd.concat([out, tmp], axis=1)

out = out.fillna('').reset_index()
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   emp_code emp_name                      holiday_date total_holiday_leaves
0        40        A  2023-04-07,2023-04-14,2023-04-21                  3.0  \
1        42        B                        2023-04-07                  1.0
2         5        J
3        31        P

    sick_date total_sick_leaves availed_date total_availed_date
0
1
2  2023-04-03               1.0
3                                 2023-04-10                1.0
```

For those who like everything done in one line:

```
out = (
    pd.concat([df[df['status'] == st]
               .groupby(['emp_code', 'emp_name'])
               .agg({ 'date' : ','.join, 'status' : 'count' })
               .set_axis(names, axis=1) for st, names in status.items()], axis=1)
    .fillna('')
    .reset_index()
    )
```